# Is it possible to spoof the From: field in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, spoofing

I am wondering if it is possible to change the From: field (not just the reply-to) in Outlook (specifically in the 2010 beta, but also interested in other versions).

I am just moving over from Linux and am used to being able to do this quite simply in some clients.

At first I thought it was the option of "Other E-Mail address" on the From drop down menu in a compose window, but that seems to do... nothing!

I want to be able to do this so I can have email look like it comes from a domain I own but do not wish to run an SMTP server on.

Comment: A definitive answer will depend on whether Outlook is using an Exchange account, or a POP/IMAP account. The OP has not clarified this.

Answer (score 3):

In the **Options** tab in the message's toolbar, click **Show From** to make sure it is enabled then change the From address.

Keep in mind, some mail clients handle messages differently so this is not guaranteed to work for every recipient. The original from address is still inside the e-mail headers.

Comment: Sorry I must be missing something, can't for the life of me see that option, where should I be right-clicking?

Comment: You should be able to right-click the field from the e-mail pane or go to **View -> Arrange -> Current -> Format** (I think it's still there).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't mean to rename the field within Outlook but to make the email appear to be from an address other than the one it was actually sent from.

Comment: I see, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in Outlook 2010, but it appears as though you can only do this if you have been provided delegated authority to send emails on behalf of the email address you are trying to send as.  i.e.  I tried to do a test email to myself from my buddy's exchange account and received the following message from the exchange server:

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:
>   <my name>
>
> You are not allowed to send this message because you are trying to send on behalf of another sender without permission to do so. Please verify that you are sending on behalf of the correct sender, or ask your system administrator to help you get the required permission.

I did this by clicking on the Options tab, then the second section from the left contained a Show Fields section which allowed selecting showing of the From field.  Then, the From word itself is a drop-down button which you need to select "Other E-mail addresses..."

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands (type them into a command prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each one):

```
telnet smtp.mailserver.com 25
HELO QA
MAIL FROM:yourid@mailserver.com
RCPT TO:yourid@mailserver.com
DATA
Subject:test mail
This a test mail
.
```

The last command is a dot (`.`), to end the email. Replace "mailserver.com" with the URL of your mail server, of course.

If you see a message like the following, then it means you've successfully spoofed the sender email:

```
250 2.0.0 qA28jUNa098936 Message accepted for delivery
```

Source: http://automatethebox.blogspot.in/2012/11/email-spoofing-how-to-spoof-email.html

Answer (score 0):

Suggest renaming title of question to be more clear: "Is it possible to spoof the From: field in Outlook?".

IMO, this is generally a Bad Idea(TM). What you should be doing is setting up multiple accounts for sending mail, so that you use the correct server for each address, instead of trying to spoof it. My apologies if this is what you really want to do, and if I just misunderstood what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I did that to remove the annoying "On Behalf Of" message when you change the sender on Microsoft Outlook. I just published the description of the issue and a free add-in to overcome this limitation: http://blog.nektra.com/main/2012/06/06/removing-the-on-behalf-of-message-from-outlook/

It is not possible to do it only with the Outlook configuration.